# Find all user controls that derives a specific base class, regarding of typeparam?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-webcontrol

I´ve a base class for all user controls: `SiteUserControlBase`. It also takes a typeparam: `SiteUserControlBase<T>`. How do I best find all controls on the page that derives from `SiteUserControlBase` regarding of the typeparam?

I use the extension method below to find all controls of type `SiteUserControlBase`, but it will exclude all controls that also uses the type param.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindControlsOfType<T>(this ControlCollection Controls) 
    where T : class
{
    T control;
    foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
    {
        if ((control = ctrl as T) != null)
        {
            yield return control;
        }

        foreach (T child in FindControlsOfType<T>(ctrl.Controls))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It also takes a typeparam" suggests you are under a misapprehension. `SiteUserControlBase` and `SiteUserControlBase<T>` are **completely different types** (in the same way that, say `Tuple<T1>` and `Tuple<T1,T2>` are also completely different types)